# styled-components: Styling components without wrapping them in containers/wrappers?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Is it possible to style a react component without having to create a container?

Here's an example of my current problem. I always need to wrap the component in a container/wrapper. Like so ...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const PitchSliderContainer = styled.input`
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
`;

const PitchSlider = () => <PitchSliderContainer
    type="range"
    min="0.9"
    max="1.1"
    step="any"
    onChange={this.props.onChange}
/>

export default PitchSlider;
```

Is there any way to style the `PitchSlider` without having to create a container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you have done is the right way. Because that's the whole point of Styled Components. To create reusable **presentational** components. Here, your `PitchSliderContainer` is one such styled `input` component. You could write a more general component that accepts certain props, and renders an `<input>` based on the props. Such a styled component should definitely have a name too.

What you're asking for could be done in another way. This is not recommended for structural components, but since your component has a single `<input>` tag, this should be okay:

```
const PitchSlider = ({ className }) => <PitchSliderContainer
    type="range"
    min="0.9"
    max="1.1"
    step="any"
    onChange={this.props.onChange}
    className={className}
/>

export default styled(PitchSlider)`
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
`;
```

Make sure you receive `className` as props and pass it down to your component.

**EDIT**: As Phil Pluckthun suggested, you could also do this:

```
const PitchSlider = styled.input.attrs({
  type: 'range',
  min: '0.9'
  max: '1.1'
  step: 'any'
  onChange: this.props.onChange
})`
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
`;
```

Comment: Another alternative would also be to use the attrs function to avoid an additional functional component entirely: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs

Comment: @PhilPlückthun That's a good suggestion, I'm adding it to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `styled`, you wrap your initial container with a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). Which means that what is returned by the `styled` function is just a regular *React* component that can be used normally, and receive *props* without an extra layer of wrapping. It could be used for example this way:

```
<ParentComponent>
  <PitchSliderContainer type='range' step='any' />
</ParentComponent>
```

See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3ym7o88pp) sandbox to see the component you defined originally being used in the page.